# Set the WorkingDirectory to user's home in launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist, services

I understand that you can change a LaunchAgent's working directory with a `WorkingDirectory` key, but is there any way to set the Working Directory to a user's home directory reliably and portably within the plist? Can I do something like:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>~</string>
```

and have it work?

Answer (score 2):

`launchd` doesn't know about shell mechansims like `~` or `$HOME`. Instead you can use one of the following

- Specify the full path in the plist
- Add `cd $HOME` at the beginning of the executedscript